# What syntax do you I need to create/POST data in a Rails API? How do I create a new Hotel entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, curl

Sometimes the VERY VERY simple stuff is the hardest stuff to find. I have something very simple that I can't seem to find online.

I've created very simple Hotel and Room models. I've done GET's via browser, curl, and iOS. I've created a simple iOS application and taken the my Rails backend JSON response data and displayed it into my app. Now I want to create data.

I've added this code to my hotels_controller

```
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token        

def create
    @hotel = Hotel.create!(params[:hotel])
    respond_with(@hotel)
end
```

Here's an awesomeprint output of my Hotel model

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base {
    :id => :integer,
    :name => :string,
    :rating => :decimal,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

I've done the following...

```
curl -X POST -d "id=11&name=YO&rating=4" http://localhost:3000/hotels

Started POST "/hotels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 13:08:05 -0700
Processing by HotelsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11", "name"=>"YO", "rating"=>"4"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name can't be blank):
```

What syntax need I be using here, to get past this error? I only have

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

in my Hotel model.

Comment: Are you sure that first code listing is valid?

Comment: did this line `@hotel = Hotel.create(params[:hotel])` work for you? it looks like a a mass assignment and should raise an error message

Comment: I'm getting this error Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms when I run a curl -X POST -d "id=11&name=blah&rating=4". Also the first code listing is just awesomeprint output.

Answer (score 0):

Add the POST endpoint to `config/routes.rb` and then run `rake routes` to check that it's set up.

As for curl, read the man page:

```
   -d, --data <data>
          (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and
          presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to
          -F, --form.

          -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the  value  of  a
          form field you may use --data-urlencode.

          If  any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-sym-
          bol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

          If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the  data  from  stdin.
          The  contents  of  the file must already be URL-encoded. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be
          done with --data @foobar.
```

FWIW, setting up an integration test may wind up being easier than manually `curl`ing.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong here, as far as I can tell, is that you should have a `Parameters` hash passed in that looks kind of like this:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"11", "hotel => {"name"=>"YO", "rating"=>"4"}}
```

That way, when you use `params['hotel']`, there's something in the `hotel` key.

By the way, thanks for the logs and stuff, and agree with @mgamba that a test would be simpler. Anything that does the post you want and you can keep watch on it.